# Multiple value for one key

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

I want to put multiple values in a list in the dictionary that has on key.

For example,

```py
time = {"created":123, "created":456, "created":799}
    print (time['created'])
```

it will print just the last value because I know the key has only one value, so it overwrites the previous ones.

Please is there a way to get all these values in a list?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You can store the values in a list corresponding to that key.

Comment: "I want to put multiple values in a list in dictionary that has on key" You can literally just do that. What *exactly* is your problem in solving this?

Comment: How about this ```{"created": [123,456, 799]}``` ? one key multiple values

Comment: @MisterMiyagi  Thank you for your reply. However,in  the file that I want to get the value of 'created' key are listed in a dictionary:

Answer (score 0):

```
time = {"created":[123,456,799]}
print (time['created'])
```

output:

```
[123, 456, 799]
```

Comment: @kareem Emad  thank you very much for your answer. The thing is in the file that I want to grab the value of "created" they are already in a Dictionary format. Moreover, there are  around 10 values for the key "created".